# Separating a String to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

How can i seperate this String:

```
"thisisanexampleforthisproblemicantsolvetestes"
```

To this array:

```
{"thisi","sanex","ampl","efor","this","prob","lemi","cant","solv","etes","tes"}
```

I want to seperate the first 10 letters in the String into 2 elemnts in an array and the rest should be every 4 letters, to one elemnt in an array.
I hope you can help me. I tried this all day but still didnt solve it

Comment: You said you tried this all day, so can you show some of your attempts?

Comment: Absolutely strange. What is this good for ?

Comment: Hint: String substring

Comment: Hint: `String[] arr = new String[2 + ((s.length() - 10) / 4)];`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input string `length >= 10` you can do something like below using streams:

```
String str = "thisisanexampleforthisproblemicantsolvetestes";
String[] splited = Stream.of(str.substring(0, 10).split("(?<=\\G.{5})"),
                             str.substring(10).split("(?<=\\G.{4})"))
                         .flatMap(e -> Arrays.stream(e))
                         .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splited));
```

where the regex `"(?<=\\G.{n})"` is used to split a string at each `nth` char

Comment: Great stuff !!!!

Comment: I dont know the meaning of stuff in englisch. In fact i want to congratulate you for this skill. However I avoid regex since 35 years (in c and java)  because it is not humanely or say unreadable.

Comment: @Norbert Thanks for your feedback. You can simply express your agreement with an upvote (arrow next to the answer up) or a downvote if you don't like my answer (arrow down).

Comment: Yes give you a upvote for your skill - however i'll never never will use regex

Answer (score 1):

More simple to understand:
Results in: thisi, sanex, ampl, efor, this, prob, lemi, cant, solv, etes, tes

```
public static List<String> strangeThingsDo(String str)
{
    List<String> li = new ArrayList<>(); 
    int len = str.length();
    if (len <= 5)
    {
         li.add(str); 
         return li;
    }
    if (len <= 10)
    {
     li.add(str.substring(0,5));
     li.add(str.substring(5));
     return li;
    }
    li.add(str.substring(0,5));
    li.add(str.substring(5,10));
    String s,rest = str.substring(10);

    int restlen = rest.length();
    int end = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < restlen;i += 4)
    {
          end = i + 4;
          if (end > restlen) 
          { s = rest.substring(i); 
            li.add(s); 
            break; 
          }
          s = rest.substring(i,end);
          li.add(s);
    }
    System.out.println("---: " + li );
    return li;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will show you how to split a string by numbers of characters. We create a method called splitToNChars() that takes two arguments. The first arguments is the string to be split and the second arguments is the split size.
This splitToNChars() method will split the string in a for loop. First we’ll create a List object that will store parts of the split string. Next we do a loop and get the substring for the defined size from the text and store it into the List. After the entire string is read we convert the List object into an array of String by using the List‘s toArray() method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SplitStringForEveryNChar {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitToNChar(text, 3)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitToNChar(text, 4)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitToNChar(text, 5)));
}
private static String[] splitToNChar(String text, int size) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();

    int length = text.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += size) {
        parts.add(text.substring(i, Math.min(length, i + size)));
    }
    return parts.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

}